# Set GPIO bank number in device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

Do you know how to set the `GPIO bank number` in the device tree for an `i2c gpio controller`?

I tried with `gpio-base` (described in the [gpio driver doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt)) but it was not very conclusive.

I have a device tree:

```
...
&i2c2 {
      pca9502: pca9502@4C {
        compatible = "nxp,pca9502";
        reg = <0x4C>;
        gpio-controller;
        /* HERE */
        gpio-base = <1>; 
     }
}
...
```

and the driver fetch the DT to find the gpio-base:

```
of_get_property(dev.of_node, "gpio-base", NULL);
```

In this case, a `gpiochip` is created with the number `2^32` giving: `gpiochip16777216`. And I can't access my GPIO using `echo XX > export`.

When I don't add `gpio-base = <1>;`, it works but the `gpiochip` number is 504 (with -1 as a default bank number) which I don't understand.

I don't know how to define the `bank number` into the device tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my issue was not linked with the device tree structure but with the `endianness` of the processor.